# Unix/Linux Alike File Permissions

Tags: php, algorithm, permissions, permutation

I am trying to create a function that will derive if the user is authorised to access a certain method based on verifying the permission level with the user type. (Similar to linux file permissions - 777)

Eg. 
Administrator : 1
Developer : 2
Contributor : 4
Public : 8

Hence, if I declare the method to allow a permission level of 15, all users will be allow to access it. Whereas, if the permission level is set at 7, the public will have no access to it.

However, I can't seem to derive a proper formula/algorithm to verify if the user type is allowed within the permission level. Can someone guide me on this? Appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple bitwise AND (the `&` operator)?

A bitwise AND will return 0 if the user lacks permission and >0  if the user is allowed access.

```
$result = $user & $permission
```

Comment: Works like magic! I didn't know there was such an operator! Thanks!